# Is ElasticSearch append API available in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-jest

I have a use case to index new documents to ElasticSearch and update existing ones.

The update can include: 1) Update/ overwrite some fields. 2) APPEND new String value to one of the existing String Array fields.
(By APPEND I mean, I don't want to lose existing values)

Is there a Java API to achieve this? I am only able to find doing this via script like this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/append-processor.html